Why are Orthodox Christians expected to go to confession if they don't distinguish between mortal and venial sins and they don't believe in Purgatory?
I assume that the average Orthodox Christian doesn't confess every minor sin right away, but is still able to receive the Eucharist with a clear conscience. On the other hand, they would want to go to confession first if they have committed a very grave sin. Without a distinction between venial and mortal sin, though, why is confession necessary at all? Without Purgatory, it would appear especially unnecessary to confess one's more trivial sins, not to mention that Orthodox priests do not even absolve sins.
On the other hand, would Catholics still be required to make regular confessions if not for their belief in Purgatory and mortal sin?

@user57467 I am a Catholic and I know what the Catechism has to say about these topics, but it does not address the question in my post.

would Catholics still be required to make regular confessions if not for their belief in Purgatory and mortal sin? That's a different question, and asking multiple questions in one question post is discouraged.

Orthodox Christians do not view confession (nor soteriology in general) in terms of merit nor through a legal lens. Confession is not about paying off any sort of debt. It is about healing by receiving forgiveness of sins.

"The Orthodox do not teach temporal punishment for sins that are forgiven, because forgiveness cancels out any kind of punishment. If God forgives someone, why would He still demand payment through satisfaction? This model denies the full power and implications of forgiveness in Christ’s death and resurrection. We agree that forgiveness of sins in absolution 'does not remedy all the disorders sin has caused,' but what is needed is a reorientation of the human person so that he functions differently, not that he 'make satisfaction for' his sins....
"The word sozein in the Greek Scriptures, which is translated 'to save,' also literally means 'to heal.' Salvation is healing by definition. With Rome’s legalistic emphasis, however, personal change is de-emphasized. The main goal is therefore to attain a certain status, that is, a 'state of grace.'
"While merit is a term that can be understood in an Orthodox sense (e.g., as a synonym for virtue or to refer to the rewards given by God to the saints), merit in Rome’s legal model is a concept foreign to the Orthodox faith. No one can 'merit' salvation, not even the saints. It is not Christ’s legal 'merit' that saves us, but rather our participation in Him."
Fr. Andrew Stephen Damick, Orthodoxy and Heterodoxy: Finding the Way to Christ in a Complicated Religious Landscape, Second Edition, Revised and Expanded. (Chesterton, IN: Ancient Faith Publishing, 2017), 85–86.

Whereas humanity fell through pride and seizing the things of God on its own terms and timing, healing comes through humility, obedience to God, and patient endurance.

"For if thou desiredst sacrifice, I would have given it.... Sacrifice to God is a broken spirit: A broken and humbled heart God will not despise" (Psalm 50:18a, 19, LXXUP)

"Count it all joy, my brothers, when you experience various trials, because you know that the testing of your faith produces endurance. And let endurance have its full effect, so that you may be perfect and complete, lacking in nothing" (James 1:2–4, BTV/TCENT)

We have an opportunity to repent, whereby we may be healed. It is about restoring communion with God, against whom we have sinned.

"Against thee only have I sinned, And done evil before thee.... Cast me not away from thy presence; And remove not thy holy Spirit from me. Restore to me the joy of thy salvation: Establish me with thy directing Spirit" (Psalm 50:6a, 13–14, LXXUP)

In some traditional Orthodox parishes, confession is required every time you wish to commune by partaking of the Mystical Supper. This has become more lax in many jurisdictions for practical/logistics reasons, but shows that the practice of confession in Orthodoxy is closely related to communion. It is not about earning anything or making a payment. It is humbling ourselves before God and preparing to partake of the medicine of immortality.

"His divine power has given us everything we need for life and godliness, through the knowledge of him who called us by glory and virtue. Through these he has given us his precious and magnificent promises, so that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature, having escaped from the corruption that is in the world because of evil desires" (2 Peter 1:3–4, BTV/TCENT)

"[We break] one Bread which is the medicine of immortality and the antidote against death, enabling us to live for ever in Jesus Christ" (St. Ignatius, Epistle to the Ephesians 20)

"So then, whoever eats this bread or drinks the cup of the Lord in a manner unworthy of the Lord will be guilty of the body and blood of the Lord. So a person should examine himself before he eats of the bread and drinks of the cup. For he who eats and drinks in an unworthy manner eats and drinks judgment on himself, since he shows no regard for the body of the Lord. That is why many among you are weak and sick, and a considerable number have fallen asleep. If we would evaluate ourselves, we would not be judged. But when we are judged by the Lord, we are disciplined so that we will not be condemned with the world" (1 Corinthians 11:27–32, BTV/TCENT)

Concerning Purgatory, this is a Roman Catholic doctrine that is not shared by Orthodox Christians.

"Orthodoxy agrees that there is a certain purgation needed for the souls of the departed destined for heaven, but that experience has never been codified with the temporal model of years of suffering employed by Rome in the purgatory doctrine. For one thing, we have no indication from the Scriptures or the Fathers that there is 'time' as we know it in the hereafter. The idea of an intermediate stage of suffering is also problematic, since to be absent from the body is to be present with the Lord (2 Cor. 5:8).
"Another problem with purgatory is that it divides salvation into two parts: getting to heaven and being 'purged' or paying off the debt of sin. The emphasis in everyday spiritual life is then placed on externalized works in order to reduce time in purgatory rather than personal transformation in order to unite with God" (Fr. Andrew Stephen Damick, 89).


I'm going to give a Protestant answer because, while incomplete, I think it is beneficial to addressing your questions, "why is confession necessary at all?" and "would Catholics still be required to make regular confessions if not for their belief in Purgatory and mortal sin?".
All Christians, whether Orthodox, Catholic or Protestant ought to confess all sins of which they are aware, at least to God in personal prayer. Protestants (at least those I would consider genuine Christians and not just people going through the motions) engage in regular corporate Confession, while private Confession is available (yes, even to Protestants!) as needed.
Scripture teaches that we are not saved by works (Ephesians 2:8-9), so we must be careful not to claim that any action on our part is "necessary" for Salvation... but Scripture also says "faith by itself, if it does not have works, is dead" (James 2:17). Scripture interprets scripture, and when we read elsewhere that outward actions are indicators of one's "allegiance", we understand that James is not saying that works are themselves salvific, but are indicators or whether one is Saved. So, too, while Repentance, necessary for Salvation, may be the result not of our own efforts but of the Spirit working within us, so too does confession serve as an indicator. How can one who does not confess their sins be truly repentant?
Having established that confession is "necessary", most sins are not against our pastors/priests, but against God and against various people. Therefore it is right that we confess our sins before God. Ideally we ought also to confess to those against whom we have sinned and ask their forgiveness. The main function, therefore, of private confession, is a service to the believer. There is benefit to giving voice to our sins to another human, and there is much benefit to hearing God's Forgiveness pronounced through a rightly chosen Servant.
I'm not familiar with Orthodoxy, but the idea that one would confess to a priest and not receive absolution (assuming that we are talking about a general practice, and not withholding absolution because the priest believes the confessor to be insincere) is somewhere between "bizarre" and "an abomination". Luther would agree.
We aren't Saved because we confess, but we confess because we are Saved. Confession is a necessary expression of repentance, and is absolutely something all (true) Christians do, regardless of belief in Purgatory or in a distinction between Mortal and Venial Sin.
